# Keeping record of lock files when editing geodatabases using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, esri-geodatabase, editing, lock

In my organization, my group edits several Geodatabases and I am trying to find a way to keep track of them when GDBs are edited.

Is there an Esri function or possible an Excel script that would keep track of lock files?

Comment: Is this for SDE or just file/personal geodatabases?

Comment: [Editor Tracking](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/manage-data/editing-fundamentals/about-tracking-an-editor-s-changes-to-data.htm) allows you to track when each individual feature in each feature class is edited in your GDB. This may be more granular than your specific needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using File Geodatabase, the only option to track feature editions is Editor Tracking (@John Comment). It added 4 fields to each table namely: Creator,CreatedDate, Editor, EditedAt

If you are using Enterprise geodatabase then you can take advantage of versioning. You can create a version for each user and manage their editions, deletions, insertions ([Version change viewer](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/java/index.htm#geodatabases/using_th641426440.htm)). In this way you have a fine grained control over any edits to your Geodatabase.

last not the least, geodatabase locks are temporary. once a user start editing a File Geodatabase, locks get created and when they are finished they get deleted.